# How to use multipart/form-data post method to upload an instance of an object to a server REST?

Tags: c#, php, post, methods, multipartform-data

I search it on the forum and i tried all the possible solutions but nothing of this works for me. i have an object Utente converted in byte[] and in json string too (i didnt know which one i had to send). 
this is the object i have to send:

```
public class Utente
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int issuperuser { get; set; }
    public string persontype { get; set; }
    public int idpersontype { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string[] permissions { get; set; }
    public List<Mese> mese { get; set; }
}
```

i tried to do this

```
void Upload(string k)
    {
        AppSettingsReader settings = new AppSettingsReader();
        string URL = settings.GetValue("BasePath", typeof(string)).ToString() + settings.GetValue("MesePath", typeof(string)).ToString();
        WebRequest richiesta = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        WebResponse risposta = (HttpWebResponse)Makerequest(richiesta).GetResponse();           
    }

    private WebRequest Makerequest(WebRequest request)
    {
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", Utente.Instance.token + "|Desktop"); 
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        return request;
    }
```

but it doesn t work so i random write code to try to do somethings...i never use 'k' but it is the json string of the object Utente
 can someone help me? at least explain how to use the multipart/form-data 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand the multipart/form-data first. You can do this here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4
As far as your problem exists, you can do a simple REST call to upload your data to the server.

Comment: ok perfect but HOW can i do rest call to upload? i have a link to do the call yes but how can i pass the data (json string or byte array) to the server?

Comment: You just need to upload the data contained in that class objects, right? If yes, you can do it via the old fashion way of passing values to parameters in REST call to your API.